# Count files in a directory with filename matching a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

The command:

```
ls /some/path/some/dir/ | grep some_mask_*.txt | wc -l
```

returns the correct number of files when doing this via ssh on bash. When I put this into a .sh Script

```
iFiles=`ls /some/path/some/dir/ | grep some_mask_*.txt | wc -l`
echo "iFiles: ${iFiles}"
```

it is always `0`. Whats wrong here?

**Solution:**
When I worked on it I found out that my "wildcard-mask" seems to be the problem. using `grep some_mask_ | grep \.txt` instead of the single grep above helped me to solve the problem for the first.

I marked the answer as solution which pretty much describes exactly what I made wrong. I'm going to edit my script now. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that `grep some_mask_*.txt` is expanded by the shell and not by grep, so most likely you have a file in the directory where grep is executed which matches `some_mask_*.txt`and that filename is then used by grep as a filter.

If you want to ensure that the pattern is used by grep then you need to enclose it in single quotes. In addition you need to write the pattern as a regexp and not as a wildcard match (which bash uses for matching). Putting this together your command line version should be:

```
ls /some/path/some/dir/ | grep 'some_mask_.*\.txt' | wc -l
```

and the script:

```
iFiles=`ls /some/path/some/dir/ | grep 'some_mask_.*\.txt' | wc -l`
echo "iFiles: ${iFiles}"
```

Note that `.` needs to be prefixed with a backslash since it has special significance as a regexp that matches a single character.

I would also suggest that you postfix the regexp with $ in order to anchor it to the end (thus ensuring that the regexp matches filenames that ends with ".txt"):

```
ls /some/path/some/dir/ | grep 'some_mask_.*\.txt$' | wc -l
```

Comment: Also with regex: `ls | grep -P "^[0-9]{12}\.jpg$" | wc -l`

Answer (score 7):

[Parsing ls is not a good thing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you want to *find* files, use `find`:

```
find /some/path/some/dir/ -maxdepth 1 -name "some_mask_*.txt" -print0
```

This will print those files matching the condition within that directory and without going into subdirectories. Using `print0` prevents weird situations when the file name contains not common characters:

```
-print0
      True; print the full file name on the standard output,  followed
      by  a  null  character  (instead  of  the newline character that
      -print uses).  This allows file names that contain  newlines  or
      other  types  of white space to be correctly interpreted by pro‐
      grams that process the find output.  This option corresponds  to
      the -0 option of xargs.
```

Then, just pipe to `wc -l` to get the final count.

---

By the way, note that

```
ls /some/path/some/dir/ | grep some_mask_*.txt
```

can be reduced to a simple

```
ls /some/path/some/dir/some_mask_*.txt
```

Comment: Hihi. I was searching for that link :).. Note that `... -printf '.' | wc -c` trick I'm using. It's perfect for counting files since it would deal nicely with newlines or whatever in filenames.

Comment: @hek2mgl yeah! I've seen it some times and it is a very smart way : )

Comment: I've also seen it on SO once. I guess it was CharlesDuffy who used that... :)

Comment: `ls /some/path/some/dir/some_mask_*.txt`produces an error if no files found. That was my starting reason to rebuild the code-line.

Comment: @Mike more than an error, it outputs some garbage. You can get rid of it by saying `ls ... 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Should be noted: the reason why `printf0` is robust is because unix paths simply cannot contain a NUL byte.

Comment: Piping null seperated strings to `wc -l` is not going to work since `wc -l` uses standard newlines. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164988/count-nul-delimited-items-in-file

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution is (for bash)

```
find -name "*pattern*" | wc -l
```

- "*" represent anything (prefix- anything before , postfix - anything after)
- wc -l : give the count
- find -name : will find file with given name in double quotes

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use `find` as shown below. The reason for that is that filenames may contain newlines which would break a script that is using `wc -l`. I'm printing just a dot per filename and count the dots with `wc -c`:

```
find /some/path/some/dir/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'some_mask_*.txt' -printf '.' | wc -c
```

or if you want to write the results to variable:

```
ifiles=$(find /some/path/some/dir/ -maxdepth 1 -name 'some_mask_*.txt' -printf '.' | wc -c)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there wouldn't be the shell version problem.

try to use escape char on your command. It likes below.

```
ls /some/path/some/dir/ | grep some_mask_\*.txt | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
iFiles=$(ls /some/path/some/dir/ | grep some_mask_*.txt | wc -l)
echo "iFiles: ${iFiles}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to *shell expansion*. You probably tested the command line in the original directory, but if you try it from another directory then it will not work anymore.

When you type:

```
grep *.txt
```

then the shell replace `*.txt` with all the file names that correspond to the pattern and then execute the command (something like `grep a.txt dummy.txt`). But you want the pattern to be interpreted by `grep` not expanded by the shell, so:

```
ls /tmp | grep '.*.cpp'
```

wille make it. Here the pattern is in the syntax of `grep` command (each command as its own syntax) and **not expanded** because it is protected with surroundings `'`.

Modify your command like:

```
a=`ls /tmp | grep '.*.cpp'`
```

Comment: better use `$()` than deprecated backticks.

Comment: There are not deprecated (many say so but it is false), but the new usage is a good advice...

Comment: Uhms, you are right. I guess many think so, there is even a question in U&L [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126927/40596). Same explained in http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: That's what POSIX says: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03

Answer (score 0):

This is quite similar to other answers, but with a bit more robustness

```
iFiles=$( find /some/path/ -name "some_mask_*.txt" -type f 2> /dev/null | wc -l )
echo "Number of files: $iFiles"
```

This limits the find to files and also pipes stderr to null, so if the find command doesn't work or has permission issues you don't get a bogus result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply first, but I did it in a different way because I don't like piping errors to /dev/null. Imo if there are errors showing up, there is a reason for it.

Comment: This is true but in this example the error would be counted in the wc and provide an inaccurate count.

Comment: Actually ignore that. Wc only counts from stdout, tested just now.

Answer (score -2):

I was writing a shell script to count the files of same format in a directory. For that I have used the below command

```
LOCATION=/home/students/run_date/FILENAME #stored the location in a variable
DIRECTORYCOUNT=$(find $LOCATION -type d -print | wc -l) using find command 
DIRECTORYCOUNT=$(find $LOCATION -type f -print | wc -l)
```

I have used above commands and enter code here it worked well